# MVC3 Finding a control by its Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, findcontrol

I have a C#.Net web app and I am trying to access one of the HTML/ASP Text Boxes in the Controller for the Edit View of my Proposal model.  In a non-MVC app, I was able to do this using `Control.ControlCollection.Find()`.  Is there an equivalent for a MVC3 project?

Comment: Are you trying to access a text box by ID within the HTML, or are you trying to access a Controller's action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for an equivalent of `Control.ControlCollection.Find()` in MVC?

In MVC your controller is not aware of *controls*.

The controller just receives data via parameters and returns data via the function result.

What do you want to do with the control in your controller code?

If you want to access the value, you should bind it to a parameter:

View:

```
<input name="MyControl" type="text" />
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string MyControl) {
    // MyControl contains the value of the input with name MyControl
}
```

Comment: @Jan....yeah, you're right. Poorly worded question. What I'm trying to do is set some default values. Brain cramp. I am now assigning the Default values the properties of the Model....

Answer (score 1):

The MVC pattern was designed to keep things separated.

- The View has no knowledge of the controller at all
- The Controller only knows that a view exists and what kind of data that it needs. It do not know ***how*** the data is render.

Hence, you can never get information about controls/tags in the view from the controller. You need to use javascript/jQuery in the view and invoke the proper action in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In an MVC-application you don't have controls like in a webform-application.
In MVC you collect your required data in the controller and pass it to the view.
Typicaly the view is a HTML-page with embedded code.
In opposite to controls in webforms which produce HTML and handles the post-backs in MVC you have to do all this manually. So you don't have controls with properties and events wich you can access easily in the controller and you have to handle all your posts with your own code.
Thats sounds as it is a lot of more work - and indeed it could be if you implement the behaviour of complex controls - but MVC applications are much better to maintain and you have 100% influence to the produced HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well probably i am late for this but it should help others in future...u can store ur value in  hidden field in view and then access that value in controller by following code..

```
Request.Form["hfAnswerOrder"].ToString();
```

Point - hfAnswerOrder is the ID of the hidden field

My Control in cshtml page..

```
@Html.Hidden("hfAnswerOrder", Model.Answers.ToList()[0].AnswerOrder)
```